# Shifting enumerate list with custom made bullets to the right

Tags: margins, enumerate, bullets

I have problems with shifting my enumerate list to the right. 
I have the following code with custom made bullet points:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate,xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[{\makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}  {\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$} }] % notice the space after "1"
   \item 1
    \item 2 
\end{enumerate}
```

Now when I try with the usual \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=2cm], I have problems with the custom made bullets. It simply does not work I have tried writing:

```
\begin{enumerate}[{\makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex} 
{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$}, leftmargin=2cm }]
```

and

```
\begin{enumerate}[{\makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex} 
{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$} }][leftmargin=2cm]
```

but nothing worked - it just compiled and the as bulletpoints I had the text "leftmargin" and in option nr.2 the list completely disappeared.

I have attached a picture of the list as it looks now.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Best Husky[image]

Comment: `\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=2cm]` is not "usual" (the standard `enumerate` does not have an optional argument). It is syntax from the  `enumitem` package which you have not used.

Comment: it would be more natural to use `itemize` than `enumerate` as you have no enumeration in the label.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you! That does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

No math mode needed – a simple `\Checkmark` from `bbding` and `enumitem` will do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label = {\fboxsep = 0pt\fbox{\scriptsize\Checkmark}}, labelsep = 1em] %
   \item First item
   \item Second item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this using the `enumitem` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}
\newlist{custom}{itemize}{4}
\newcommand\CustomBullet{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$}%
}
\setlist[custom]{
  label=\CustomBullet,
  leftmargin=20mm
}

\begin{document}

  \noindent Some words before
  \begin{custom}
   \item 1
   \item 2
  \end{custom}
  Some words after

\end{document}
```

The code produces:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you so much! This did work. However, my problem is now that the list works until the last item. The last item is not aligned. I am not sure what is causing it. I have added a photo.

Comment: @Husky653 Please don't add only a photo: add some code that reproduces the problem